# Random Images from same url

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays

I was given a prompt to loop through items in a javascript object. Each item has an imageUrl property that points to this url: https://www.placebeard.it/400x400 This url is supposed to generate random images on each visit, but when I loop over the objects I end up getting the same image 25 times. When I inspect the page and click on the images I get random images. This is a codepen project, could that be the problem?

Here is a sample of the code used to get the image

```
const makeCard = (item) => {
  let card = document.createElement('div');
  card.classList.add('card', 'p-0');

  // card image
  let image = document.createElement('img');
  image.classList.add('card-img-top');
  image.src = `${item.imageUrl}`;
  console.log(image.src);
  card.appendChild(image);

  //... append to container
}
```

Thanks

Comment: i would guess that your browser is caching the image for some reason. try appending `'?'+Math.random()` to the url and see if that fixes it. You could also add the header `Cache-Control: no-cache`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a trick that your browser plays: because you point the image to the same URL, the browser will think it's the same image. You can get in front of it by adding a dummy query string and a random value, e.g.:

```js
const makeCard = (item) => {
  let card = document.createElement('div');
  card.classList.add('card', 'p-0');

  // card image
  let image = document.createElement('img');
  image.classList.add('card-img-top');
  image.src = `${item.imageUrl}?random=${Math.random()}`; // notice this
  console.log(image.src);
  card.appendChild(image);

  //... append to container
}
```

And you should get different images (servers usually ignore query strings they don't recognize).

Answer (score 0):

You Can Add Images src in json file and transform the json file to the javascript object and make a loop with images count

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).